# Concatenate 2 columns given a condition

Tags: mysql

I am having following scenario: I have a table lets say `X` where fields are

```
 -------------------------
 | City      | Country   |
 ------------------------|
 | Melbourne | Australia |
 | Phoenix   | USA       |
 | Manchester| USA       |
 | Manchester| UK        |
 | Phoenix   | USA       |
 | Pune      | India     |
 ------------------------
```

I am trying to update `city` column only when `city` are same and `country` are different. I have tried doing

> UPDATE X SET (`City`) = CONCAT(`CITY`,`COUNTRY`) WHERE = ?

What should be where clause?

**EDIT:**

Output should look like

```
 ------------------------------
 | City           | Country   |
 -----------------------------|
 | Melbourne      | Australia |
 | Phoenix        | USA       |
 | Manchester, USA| USA       |
 | Manchester, UK | UK        |
 | Phoenix        | USA       |
 | Pune           | India     |
 ------------------------------
```

Comment: you mean if you choose country then it comes its cities ?

Comment: not clear with your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE X inner join X X_1 on X.city = X_1.city
SET X.City=CONCAT(X.city, ', ', X.Country)
WHERE X.country <> X_1.country
```

this sets City name to `CONCAT(X.city, ', ', X.Country)` only where the same City name exists in multiple countries.

**EDIT:** i think i prefer this other version:

```
UPDATE
  X inner join
  (select city from X group by city having count(*)>1) X_dup
  on X.city = X_dup.city
SET X.City=CONCAT(X.city, ', ', X.Country)
```

I'm using all these strange joins because MySql doesn't allow you to update a table if you are referencing it in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE X SET (City) = CONCAT(CITY,', ',COUNTRY) 
WHERE CITY IN 
    ( 
    SELECT tmp.City FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT x2.City, x2.Country FROM X AS x2) AS tmp 
    GROUP BY tmp.City HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 
    )
```

Comment: +1 nested query also resolves the problem of updating a table while you are referencing it in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can get `City` of all duplicate towns by query like this:

```sql
SELECT City, COUNT(City) AS Count
FROM X
GROUP BY City
HAVING Count > 1
```

It would be easiest to use `IN` in condition (only one column), so will encapsulate this:

```sql
SELECT City
FROM (
    SELECT City, COUNT(City) AS Count
    FROM X
    GROUP BY City
    HAVING Count > 1
) AS t1
```

Now we have to push all data into temporary table because mysql doesn't work when you try using nested table select while updating the same table:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (VARCHAR(255) city);
INSERT INTO tmp (
    SELECT City
    FROM (
        SELECT City, COUNT(City) AS Count
        FROM X
        GROUP BY City
        HAVING Count > 1
    ) AS t1
)
```

And now we may launch update:

```sql
UPDATE X SET (City) = CONCAT(CITY,COUNTRY)
WHERE `City` IN (SELECT City FROM tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
GROUP_CONCAT()
```

Returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/